# Using Multiple CGAffineTransforms On Text Matrix

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I am displaying text using Quartz. Here is my code:

```
    CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSelectFont(myContext, "Helvetica", 12, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetCharacterSpacing(myContext, 8);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(myContext, kCGTextFillStroke);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(myContext, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(myContext, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(myContext,CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0));
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(myContext, textOrigin.x, textOrigin.y,[way.name UTF8String],[way.name length]);
```

This displays my text the right way up and in the right direction, however I also need to add a rotation to the text using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);`. I can't seem to work out how to aply two affine transforms to the text matrix, though, without one overwriting the other. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can combine matrices with [CGAffineTransformConcat](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformConcat), e.g.

```
CGAffineTransform finalTransf = CGAffineTransformConcat(t1, t2);
```

If you just need to apply rotation to an existing matrix, use [CGAffineTransformRotate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformRotate), e.g.

```
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0);
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformRotate(t, M_PI/2);
CGContextSetTextMatrix(myContext, t);
```

Answer (score 1):

To supplement @kennytm's answer, to apply more than two transforms you can do the following:

```
var t = CGAffineTransformIdentity
t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t, CGFloat(100), CGFloat(300))
t = CGAffineTransformRotate(t, CGFloat(M_PI_4))
t = CGAffineTransformScale(t, CGFloat(-1), CGFloat(2))
// ... add as many as you want, then apply it to to the view
imageView.transform = t
```

[Go here to see my full answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30929987/3681880)

Comment: You are on the way, but applying order of transforms is very important. According to that, the result will be different apparently.