# How to apply multiple transforms in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, transform, cgaffinetransform

I would like to apply multiple transforms to a `UIView` (or subclass of `UIView`), such as translate, rotate, and scale. I know that two transforms can be applied with [`CGAffineTransformConcat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformConcat), but how do I do it if I have three or more transforms?

I have seen these questions:

- [Applying multiple transforms to a UIView / CALayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111277/applying-multiple-transforms-to-a-uiview-calayer)
- [Using Multiple CGAffineTransforms On Text Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047972/using-multiple-cgaffinetransforms-on-text-matrix)

but these questions are asking something different, and the given answers just talk about applying two transforms with `CGAffineTransformConcat`. Also, they use Objective-C rather than Swift.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You can apply multiple transforms by stacking them on top of each other.

```
var t = CGAffineTransform.identity
t = t.translatedBy(x: 100, y: 300)
t = t.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 4)
t = t.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 2)
// ... add as many as you want, then apply it to to the view
imageView.transform = t
```

Or more compactly (but not necessarily as readable):

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: 100, y: 300).rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 4).scaledBy(x: -1, y: 2)
```

This series of transforms produces the image on the right:

[image]

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4679328/3681880) for teaching me how to do it.

## Notes

- The order in which you apply the transforms matters. For example, if the transforms were done in the opposite order it would produce the following result.

  ```
  t = t.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 2)
  t = t.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 4)
  t = t.translatedBy(x: 100, y: 300)
  ```

[image]

## See also

- [CGAffineTransform Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/) (docs)
- [Transforms](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html) (docs)
- [Swift: Translating and Rotating a CGContext, A Visual Explanation (iOS/Xcode)](http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2014/11/swift-translating-and-rotating.html)
- [Demystifying CGAffineTransform](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/demystifying-cgaffinetransform.html)

*This answer has been tested with Swift 4*

Answer (score 33):

In Swift 3, these have been replaced by functions on CGAffineTransform itself, which can be chained.

```
extension CGAffineTransform {
    public func translatedBy(x tx: CGFloat, y ty: CGFloat) -> CGAffineTransform
    public func scaledBy(x sx: CGFloat, y sy: CGFloat) -> CGAffineTransform
    public func rotated(by angle: CGFloat) -> CGAffineTransform
}
```

so for example

```
let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 3.0).translatedBy(x: 12, y: 9).rotated(by: 17.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

the trick is that
`view.transform.translatedBy(x: 100, y: 100)` is NOT changing `view.transform`. it just returns the new `CGAffineTransform` that you need to ASIGN back to `view.transform`.

```
view.transform = view.transform.translatedBy(x: 100, y: 100)
```

You can do that as many times as you need or in a sequence

```
view.transform = view.transform.translatedBy(x: 100, y: 100).rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 2).scaledBy(x: 2, y: 2)
```