# Swift iOS -Apply additional changes to transform when using CATransform3D .m34 property to change perspective in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, catransform3d

I'm reading a book on animations [iOS Core Animation: Advanced Techniques](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EHJCORC). The book is in Objective C. I'm not fluent in Objective C. I understand what the .m34 property does but when I apply the book's code to Swift the perspective isn't changing. The problem is I cannot seem to add to an existing transform like [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30929987/4833705).

My code:

```
var tranform = CATransform3DIdentiy
transfrom.m34 = -1 / 500
transform = CATransform3DMakerotation(CGFloat(Double.pi/4), 0, 1, 0) // this is just creating a new transform instead of adding to the existing one
viewIwantTransformed.layer.transfrom = transform
```

Books Code:

```
@implementation ViewController 
- (void) viewDidLoad 

 { [super viewDidLoad]; 

   // create a new transform CATransform3D 
   transform = CATransform3DIdentity;

   // apply perspective 
   transform.m34 = - 1.0 / 500.0; 

  // rotate by 45 degrees along the Y axis
  transform = CATransform3DRotate( transform, M_PI_4, 0, 1, 0);

  // apply to layer 
  self.viewIwantTransformed.layer.transform = transform; 

} @end
```

Result

[image]

Comment: try this line transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, M_PI_4, 0, 1, 0)

Comment: @ Jigar Darji hey thanks that worked! If you make it the official answer I'll accept it

Comment: accept my answer

Comment: it says I have to wait 4 minutes

Comment: ok np try after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, M_PI_4, 0, 1, 0)
```

instead by

```
transform = CATransform3DMakerotation(CGFloat(Double.pi/4, 0, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Swift 4 says to use Double.pi instead of M_PI. The answer is correct either way though, thanks. Here is what the warning suggested, Change M_PI_4 to Double.pi/4. So the code would be transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat(Double.pi/4), 0, 1, 0)

Comment: hmm there is some syntax warning